# Null fields when I use @JsonProperty for retrieve object from MongoDB by Spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jackson, spring-data-mongodb

I have some problem with Spring JPA, MongoDB and Jackson when I use `@JsonProperty` to use a different name for the json/db and java field.
I receive json and save them into collections, for example

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="message")
public class Message implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("raw")
    private Raw raw;

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private Meta meta;      
}
```

with Raw :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="raw")
public class Raw {

    private String dlc;

    @JsonProperty("can_id")
    private String canId;

    @JsonProperty("can_data")
    private String canData;
}
```

I'm using lombok for the get,set and constructor. I had the `message` into database before change the field name (using for instance `canData` instead of `can_data`) and when I retrieved the object from database this renamed fields were null. So I removed the message and stored again and finally work, I made this because into mongodb I see `_class:"com.domain.Message"`.
This is the first problem: every time I change my java class all the stored data give me this problem?
But I have problem even with manually inserted json into Mongodb: the fields where I use `@JsonProperty` are null when I make the query like this:

```
@Query("{ 'can_id' : ?0 }")
Severity findByCanId(String canId);
```

`Severity` is so:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="severity")
public class Severity implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("can_id")
    @Indexed
    private String canId;       

    @JsonProperty("can_name")
    private String canName;

    private Integer ss;

    private Integer ps;

    private Integer fs;

    private Integer os;
}
```

The query return me a `Severity` object with `canId` and `canName` null. 
Do you know how can I fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the name of field into database I fix using `@Field("can_id")` but the problem about the changing of java class stil present

Answer (score 0):

You should replace @JsonProperty with  @BsonProperty